# Problema con enlace del live de video de YouTube utilizando ID de Canal

Tags: php, youtube

Buen día, siempre hemos utilizado el siguiente HTML para embeber y reproducir los videos en vivo por streaming de nuestro canal de Youtube:

```html
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
<iframe width="208" height="118" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=[ID_DEL_CANAL]" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Esto nos permitía no tener que depender del ID de cada video, y utilizando el ID de nuestro canal, al reproducir el video del live de streaming del momento.

A partir de Julio de 2023, solamente se muestra el mensaje "Este video no está disponible."

Hemos revisado la configuración Avanzada de nuestro Canal y no ha cambiado nada, tampoco recibimos ninguna notificación por parte de YouTube, utilizamos contenido libre de derechos de autor.

---

SOLUCION ALTERNATIVA:

```
<?php
    // ¡Aquí reemplacen por el nombre de su canal !!
    // ---------------------------------------------
    $nombre_canal = "NOMBREDELCANAL";

    $url = "https://www.youtube.com/@$nombre_canal/live";

    $html = file_get_contents($url);

    // Luego del = empieza el id del video que se está transmitiendo en el canal
    $buscar = '/watch?v=';

    $posicionInicio = strpos($html, $buscar);

    if ($posicionInicio !== false) {
        // Se avanza a la posición de inicio después de '/watch?v='
        $posicionInicio += strlen($buscar);
        
        // Se busca la siguiente comilla doble después de '/watch?v='
        $posicionFin = strpos($html, '"', $posicionInicio);
        
        if ($posicionFin !== false) {
            // Nos quedamos con la parte de la cadena que corresponde al ID del video
            $id_video = substr($html, $posicionInicio, $posicionFin - $posicionInicio);

            echo "ID del video: $id_video";
        } else
            echo "No se encontró la comilla doble después de '/watch?v='.";
    } else
        echo "'/watch?v=' no fue encontrado en el contenido HTML.";
    ?>
```

Comment: @OCHOA, gracias por la corrección con respecto a la publicación.

Answer (score 0):

He reproducido tu código y en mi canal funciona. Solo que cambié el HTML por:

```html
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"> <!-- esta es tu clase -->
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $id_video; ?>" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Te recomiendo que siempre uses lo que el desarrollador te proporciona. Yo solo tuve que copiar el modelo de `embedded` que YouTube proporciona.

Resultado:
[image: Youtube]

Comment: Hola @OCHOA, buen día, sí, ese mismo html utilizamos una vez obtenido el ID del video en vivo.

Comment: Tu `HTML` no es igual al "mío", el tuyo no funciona, el "mío" si. Entre comillas porque es de YouTube jeje, pero vamos que no es igual, tu `HTML` a mi no me funcionó, el que yo he puesto, lo has probado o no?? Por cierto a mi me trae el ultimo **Live** que hice...

Comment: Hola OCHOA, claro, el HTML del principio de la publicación, es el que utilizábamos con el ID del "Canal", antes de Julio, no es el mismo que utilizamos ahora para el ID del Video. Solamente agregamos la solución con PHP, no el HTML que usamos ahora. Perfecto que lo aclares, para los que deseen utilizar por completo la solución alternativa. Gracias.

Comment: No entiendo entonces, funciona lo que yo te puse o no?? Sino funciona pueda que sea algo de tu web. Porque como ya vez en la captura, mi código si manda a llamar al ultimo Live de un canal...

Comment: Hola Ochoa, sí funciona, lo que te comenté antes fue que estábamos utilizando el HTML de Youtube para usar el ID del Canal, no del ID de cada video a reproducir. Ahora como no es posible, por el momento, usar el ID del canal en la url, se toma el ID del video en vivo, y se muestra como vos lo visualizaste en el HTML. Saludos !!